# Can we export our flutter package without exposing our code?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

Can we our flutter package in some flutter app without giving them our package code as a whole (without publishing it in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/)).

I want to make a package and give it to some other app for use but I don't want them to make changes in code. Like in android, we export our code and give them just executable code?

Comment: I think you only have the license to protect you from that, as dart dependencies pull the source code. Either if they are pulled from pub.dev or github. Obfuscation might improve this a little bit but I don't see a more correct solution.

Comment: You can compile your code into native libraries and integrate them into a Flutter plugin. Exposing bridging code does not matter.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do it? @yushulx

Comment: @AkshatTamrakar for example, you can build Android code into an aar file as the SDK. Then create a [Flutter Android plugin](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) with the aar file.  I'm writing a [Flutter plugin](https://github.com/yushulx/flutter_barcode_sdk) for Android, iOS, web, Windows, Linux and macOS. You can see how to bridge Dart code and Java code.

Comment: @AkshatTamrakar did you get the solution for this.
If Yes, could you please share it here.